# Why am I getting unexpected indent error on an empty line?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is a cog file for a discord.py rewrite based bot. As you can see, it is completely empty except for the class and the setup, but still I'm recieving an `unexpected indent`error. Does anyone know what's causing this error?

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Turn on display of whitespace.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62385744/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't any real error, I guess.
Only a linting error.
Deleting the line may do the trick.

Some linters require you to have a maximum of two empty lines between some statements.

Comment: Like which lintere?

Comment: Flake8 for example gives you an message. 
(too many blank lines (3))

Answer (score 0):

Errors occurs when part of your code is indented with spaces, while other parts are indented with tabs. The best practice is to use four spaces instead of tabs.